# allocate more than 1 GB memory on 32 bit XP

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory, memory-management

I'v run into an odd problem, my process cannot allocate more than what seems to be slightly below 1 GiB. Windows Task Manager "Mem Usage" column shows values close to 1 GiB when my software gives a `bad_alloc` exception. Yes, i'v checked that the value passed to memory allocation is sensible. ( no race condition / corruption exists that would make this fail ). Yes, I need all this memory and there is no way around it. ( It's a buffer for images, which cannot be compressed any further )

I'm not trying to allocate the whole 1 GiB memory in one go, there a few allocations around 300 MiB each. Would this cause problems? ( I'll try to see if making more smaller allocations works any better ). Is there some compiler switch or something else that I must set in order to get past 1 GiB? I've seen others complaining about the 2 GiB limit, which would be fine for me.. I just need little bit more :). I'm using VS 2005 with SP1 and i'm running it on a 32 bit XP and it's in C++.

Comment: Two things that I can think of, smaller allocations and please let 32-bit operating systems outside the realm of embedded systems die soon. And because of corporate policy I am stuck on 32-bit windows 7 with 2.8 of 4 GB memory usable which is why I am wishing for its timely demise.

Comment: It saddens me deeply that I'm bound by the limits of a 32-bit OS. It's just something I have to live with, for now.

Comment: SysInternals have some tools to help you check for memory fragmentation. What happens if you do the 1 GB allocation at the start of the application?

Comment: I'll check on the SysInternals tools, any tips for them? I don't allocate the 1 GiB in one go. There are multiple allocations around 300 MiB each. I get close to 1 GiB without any problems.

Comment: Virtual memory can be subject to fragmentation. Apps that make small numbers of large allocations will see a problem first.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is much smaller allocations, like 1 MB each. If they work, you are running into fragmentation issues. Just try it. If they don’t work, that would be a useful fact to add to your question.

Comment: Oh and i do have 3 GiB memory on this machine, there is about 1 GiB free when i get the exception. One would think that it would contain another 300 MiB continous section, but I haven't had a poke with any tool yet.

Comment: What you see in task manager is `private working set`. But you should check `commit size`.

Comment: There is no "commit size" column in my version of Windows Task Manager v 5.1 I checked the list under View - Select Columns ...

Comment: Use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896653) from sys internals. I believe, it is called _virtual size_ on the _performance_ tab of process properties.

Comment: I've regularly allocated upwards of 1.8 GiB under Windows XP 32-bit _no problemo_, with chunks of dozens to hundreds of megabytes among the allocations. Maybe you're linking with not few dynamic libraries? I've found that at times (especially if someone was so "smart" as to use randomized base addresses) DLLs can greatly screw up your address space when otherwise everything would be just fine. There are often big "holes" between DLLs (use Sysinternals' VMMap frag view to see) which eat away huge portions of address space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a 32-bit OS, a process has a 4GB address space *in total*.

On Windows, half of this is off-limits, so your process has 2GB.

This is 2GB of contiguous memory. But it gets fragmented. Your executable is loaded in at one address, each DLL is loaded at another address, then there's the stack, and heap allocations and so on. So while your process probably has enough free address space, there are no contiguous blocks large enough to fulfill your requests for memory. So making smaller allocations will probably solve it.

If your application is compiled with the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag, it will be allowed to use as much of the remaining 2GB as Windows can spare. (And the value of that depends on your platform and environment.

- for 32-bit code running on a 64-bit OS, you'll get a full 4-GB address space
- for 32-bit code running on a 32-bit OS without the /3GB boot switch, the flag means nothing at all
- for 32-bit code running on a 32-bit OS with the /3GB boot switch, you'll get 3GB of address space.

So really, setting the flag is always a good idea if your application can handle it (it's basically a capability flag. It tells Windows that *we* can handle more memory, so if Windows can too, it should just go ahead and give us as large an address space as possible), but you probably can't rely on it having an effect. Unless you're on a 64-bit OS, it's unlikely to buy you much. (The /3GB boot switch is necessary, and it has been known to cause problems with drivers, especially video drivers)

Comment: On XP you also need to use the /3GB boot.ini switch.

Comment: I just didn't believe that my software would fragment the memory so much, but that just seems to be the case :) I got around 1.6 GiB by making an exception handler that attemtps to allocate smaller and smaller pieces until it succeeds. I tried using the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag, but I didn't use the 3GB switch. I saw mentioned that this would have a performance hit on the program, is this true / big?

Comment: @justanothercoder: well, it's very easy to cause fragmentation. Allocate a single byte in the right place, and your 2GB address space has been reduced to two 1GB address spaces. Two more bytes in the right places, and you have four 512MB ones. Of course, usually allocations are placed to minimize fragmentation, but my point is that it is very easy to fragment your memory space

Comment: I tried to design in such a way that it wouldn't do that :/ Apparently I didn't succeed.

Comment: @justanothercoder: Without the /3GB switch on XP, the LARGEADDRESSAWARE won't accomplish much - see this page for info on enabling it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508  I never experienced any noticeable performance issues using this configuration, although some video drivers used to have issues when this mode was enabled - I don't know if this is still the case.

Comment: Addtionally, for XP, you might get better results by enabling the Low Fragmentation Heap (on by default on Win7) - details on that are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: RE the /3GB switch.... [try not to misunderstand it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/22/218527.aspx)

Comment: +1 for making others aware of "LARGEADDRESSAWARE" very good engineering solution.

Answer (score 4):

Allocating big chunks of continuous memory is always a problem.
It is very likely to get more memory in smaller chunks

You should redesign your memory structures.

Comment: Not actually neccessary, i'll just give a smaller buffer than what was asked for, my code didn't seem to care :)  I made a loop that tries to allocate, if it fails, it tries to allocate a smaller piece.. this goes on until it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to suspect the larger 300MB allocations.  Your process will be able to get close to 2GB (3 if you use the /3GB boot.ini switch and LARGEADDRESSAWARE link flag), but not as a large contiguous block.

Typical solutions for this are to break up the requests into tiles or strips of fixed size (say 256x256x4 bytes) and write an intermediate class to hide this representation detail.

You can quickly verify this by writing a small allocation loop that allocate blocks of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from MSDN. 1GB rings a bell from here:

> This parameter must be greater than or equal to 13 pages (for example,
>   53,248 on systems with a 4K page size), and less than the system-wide
>   maximum (number of available pages minus 512 pages). The default size
>   is 345 pages (for example, this is 1,413,120 bytes on systems with a
>   4K page size).

Here they mentioned that default maximum number of pages allowed for a process is 345 pages which is slightly more than 1GB.

Comment: That is slightly more than 1 MB, not 1 GB.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a few big allocs like that to do, I use the Windows function VirtualAlloc, to avoid stressing the default allocator.

Another way forward might be to use [nedmalloc](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/) in your project.